# Задача "Chinese Remainder Theorem"

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода

> На входе - 4 числа n1, r1, n2, r2  (при этом n1 > 0, n2 > 0, 0 <=r1 <
>   n1, 0 <= r2 < n2) Необходимо найти число r, такое, чтобы  0<= r < n1 *
>   n2, r % n1 = r1, r % n2 = r2

Имеется рабочий код:

```
# определение наибольшего общего делителя - алгоритм Евклида

def gcd(a, b):
    assert a >= 0 and b >= 0 and a + b > 0

    while a > 0 and b > 0:
        if a >= b:
            a = a % b
        else:
            b = b % a
    return max(a, b)

# расширенный алгоритм Евклида
def extended_gcd(a, b):
    # assert c % gcd(a, b) == 0
    p = 1
    q = 0
    r = 0
    s = 1

    while a != 0 and b != 0:
        if a >= b:
            a = a - b
            p = p - r
            q = q - s
        else:
            b = b - a
            r = r - p
            s = s - q
    if a != 0:
        x = p
        y = q
    else:
        x = r
        y = s
    return x, y

def diophantine(a, b, c):
    # assert c % gcd(a, b) == 0
    # return (x, y) such that a * x + b * y = c
    (u, v) = extended_gcd(a, b)
    x = u * (c // gcd(a, b))
    y = v * (c // gcd(a, b))
    return x, y

def ChineseRemainderTheorem(n1, r1, n2, r2):
    (x, y) = diophantine(n1, n2, gcd(n1, n2))
    r = r1 * y * n2 + r2 * x * n1
    while r < 0:
        r += (n1 * n2)
    return r
```

Тест:

```
n1 = 686579304
r1 = 295310485
n2 = 26855093
r2 = 8217207
a = (ChineseRemainderTheorem(n1, r1, n2, r2))
print(a)
print(a % n1)
print(a % n2)
```

На выходе:

```
2988289728658869317843077
295310485
8217207
```

Проверяющая система не пропускает из-за того, что работает долго.
Где можно соптимизироваться? (первые 3 функции убрать не получится - они зашиты в проверяющую систему)

Comment: и да, а вы уверены что ответ правильный? n1*n2 как бы меньше a. Замените `while r < 0:
        r += (n1 * n2)` на `r %= n1 * n2`

Comment: @pavel и правда, какое-то неприлично большое число получилось))) Теперь все правильно, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Пайтон не оптимизирующий интерпретатор. Он делает то что вы его просите.
Поэтому в 2 раза быстрее будет например если

```
x = u * (c // gcd(a, b))
y = v * (c // gcd(a, b))
```

заменить на:

```
_ = c // gcd(a, b)
x = u * _
y = v * _
```